# Connecting a standalone temperature probe to a Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, temperature

I have a standalone temperature probe.
I have also a raspberry pi.

I would like to get the data from the temperature probe to the pi.

I have thought about cutting the probe and using direct but then found a breakout board would be required to amplify the voltage difference.
(seems futile as the standalone works)

**Q. How could i integrate the temperature readings from this standalone device to my Raspberry pi?**

[The standalone probe](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Digital-Reptile-Thermometer-Hygrometer-Remote/dp/B01LY0CABC/ref=sr_1_27?crid=70NUYY95IFBL&keywords=digital%20thermometer&qid=1558365362&s=pet-supplies&sprefix=digital%20t%2Cpets%2C141&sr=1-27)

Comment: Welcome! Unfortunately there are two problems here.  First, questions about the *usage* of the off the shelf devices are not permitted, this site is for original design questions only.  Next, your sales link does not provide any engineering information about the sensor used by the thermometer, meaning that guessing would be required, a category of question also not permitted.  Likely you should purchase a temperature sensor *known* to be easily interfaced to a pi, probably either something USB based with known Linux compatibility or something with an i2c interface and pi library.

Comment: Ok, this is the wrong place i guess. I am trying to solve a problem with what i own already. To learn and make use of existing things. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Derple like Chris mentioned this may not be the right forum for this question. That aside, if you've already bought that sensor you have one of two ways in my opinion to interface it. 1.) Open up the black unit that houses the IC and display, if the probes are using a common interface such as SPI/I2C you're lucky as you can tap those points. You can also look up the datasheet of the IC you find inside and trace the PCB lines to figure out which pins are connected from Probe to controller. If the IC uses a non standard protocol this may not work out. Input from probes to IC is one aspect ,..

Comment: ..you can also check if the pins connecting the output ie LCD display are accessible/using a standard protocol interface 2. If none of these work the easiest way would be to hook up a Pi camera and run OCR on the image reading, this way you don't have to handle calibration of the probe itself and other issues.

Comment: If you are happy to replace the probe with a new one, get yourself a DS18B20 temperature probe. They interface easily with the Pi and provide nice accurate results. [see here](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-11-ds18b20-temperature-sensing/overview)

Comment: I disagree with the first comment. The site guide says "Focus on questions about an actual problem you have faced. Include details about what you have tried and exactly what you are trying to do."  That says to me that asking how to use a probe with a controller board (R Pi) is within the realm here.

Comment: @CrossRoads - no, because there's no **engineering documentation** of the type of probe in question.  That's both a specific reason the question is off topic, and also the primary problem behind the general ban on usage questions.  Buying consumer products for parts really only works when you know how they work and as a result of that know that the parts they contain are suitable; that's unlikely to be the case here without additional purchases especially as the pi has no analog input capability.

Comment: peufeu pointed out that the probe does not have a way to interface with a R Pi. I think that answers the "actual problem" being faced and thus does make it on target.

Comment: Also, the waterproof DS18B20 probe is worth $2 so it's not worth spending time looking for a kludgey solution to not spend $2...

Comment: I've used the waterproof probes I linked (or one of their many clones) with an arduino, and they work well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your thermometer doesn't seem to have any way to talk to the rPi.

It is much simpler to get a [DS18B20 probe](https://www.google.fr/search?q=ds18b20%20waterproof%20sensor) for about $2 on the 'net, and google a [tutorial](http://www.circuitbasics.com/raspberry-pi-ds18b20-temperature-sensor-tutorial/) to interface it with your Pi. It's a digital probe, so you don't need to amplify or condition an analog signal.